# Location of MetroTwit executable

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts

I installed MetroTwit's desktop version and want to create a shortcut for it. Now, the shortcut asks for an executable path. There is no entry for MetroTwit or "Pixel Tucker Pty Ltd". The shortcut in this folder `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Pixel Tucker Pty Ltd` shows this:

[image]

I remember finding the executable once but now I'm unable to find it. I have looked in ProgramData, Program Files and AppData but no luck. Please help.

Comment: [**ClickOnce**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) app updates [create new folders](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/where-do-i-put-my-data-to-keep-it-safe-from-clickonce-updates/), so the identified path will change in future. Also see [Can I set a ClickOnce application as the default program to open a filetype on a PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/364053/can-i-set-a-clickonce-application-as-the-default-program-to-open-a-filetype-on-a) for more details about such apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was located in this directory for me:

> C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\400XBXXD.QQM\DEY27NQL.250\metr..tion_72baef66840e297_0001.0001_6cbe5111d1dfa4f1

Here is how I found it:

Launch Task Manager:
[image: Task Manager]

Find the Following Listed:
[image: MetroTwit Process]

Right Click on It:
[image: Open File Location]

Here is what the folder looks like:
[image: File Location]