# How to define installation directory for Github for windows?

Tags: windows, git

Github for Windows is a "one-click install" thing. There is a problem with it: there are no setup options. It only installs in `%appData%\Local\` under `\GitHub`, `\Apps\2.0\YYZRRD9X.HWG\RVTJXJ3M.LBH\github.exe_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_none_a7edba33c398fcf9`, `\Apps\2.0\YYZRRD9X.HWG\RVTJXJ3M.LBH\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_12384c781d7f8ad4`

I have file execution blocked in all of `%AppData%` for obvious reasons. Is there a way to set the installation directory?

Comment: What are those obvious reasons, because, I don't know them.  I think it crazy virtual every application is designed to use %AppData% as a storage location. You should be able to copy and paste the data in that folder and place it in another directory of your choice.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents writing and reading, only execution. The reason is exactly what you described: every application is designed to use %AppData% as storage. Presence of executable files in this folder is uncontrollable, so I do not allow them to be executed. Therefore it's only safe to execute from Windows and Program Files (where it requires very explicit permissions to place files). Looking into the files and their relationships now.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows) is a related question with specific instructions for the solution I describe in my first comment.

Comment: **I was** going to submit a specific answer, but the paths you provide are **not complete** so I can't.

Comment: @Ramhound
Git installs in the following folders:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\GitHub\`, 
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\YYZRRD9X.HWG\RVTJXJ3M.LBH\github.exe_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_none_a7edba33c398fcf9\`, 
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\YYZRRD9X.HWG\RVTJXJ3M.LBH\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_12384c781d7f8ad4`

Comment: those paths are not the complete paths, hence the **gith..tion** contained within the one.  If I think about it, I will submit an answer, when I have access to a virtual machine.

Comment: @Ramhound, at first, I thought that there was something missing, as well, but it looks like the path just has two periods in it: http://s12.postimg.org/o26xt0kal/Github_For_Windows.png

Also, it looks like this thing is messier than I first thought: seems like all the folders on the screenshot are part of github for desktop. Will have to uninstall it and try portable version.

Comment: You should indeed do that.  I linked to how you can add GItHub to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github for Windows is a [ClickOnce installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx), and as a user you can't control the ClickOnce installer's target folder.  Instead they will always be installed into the "ClickOnce application cache", which is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`.

> ClickOnce applications are always installed in the Apps subdirectory of local application data.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145422/225906)

> ClickOnce Deployment will install an application in the user Application Cache per user (not in X:\Programe files\folder) and will be managed by the ClickOnce service.  There is no way you can install it to another folder directly using ClickOnce. This means you cannot change the ClickOnce installation location.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51b8c600-bbc6-41a9-b345-62afa0dddf98/faq-where-is-the-location-of-clickonce-installation-and-what-are-the-restrictions-of-clickonce)

> Nope. You can't. One of the design goals of ClickOnce applications is that they require no administrative privileges, and the only places you can write with impunity on Vista and Windows Fabulous (7) are under the user's profile.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c7d00c2-2473-4fd5-b815-30066383eb47/change-installation-folder-for-a-click-once-app)

> The philosophy behind ClickOnce is a bit different to normal programs installed in "C:\Program Files". By installing the application in the user's directory, the application can be installed without having admin rights and the automatic updating system can work without having any awful security issues.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/364075/23133)

Comment: Thanks. I get it. Last point seems to be very conflicting, though. Installing applications without having admin rights is as insecure as it gets. Seems to be no purpose avoiding security issues after that, since they already dumped security into trash anyway. Now on to next question: how to move a ClickOnce application to a different directory after installation? Oh how I miss chmod when working in Windows.

Comment: "Installing applications without having admin rights is as insecure as it gets."  It forces the author to write programs that cannot have Admin access, and since they're sandboxed and trapped at the user-level, there's way less to worry about security-wise.  on the flip-side, if they wanted to install into the Program Files folder the installer would need to be given administrator permission.  Knowing that, and assuming the installer was a piece of disguised malware, which one seems safer?